# Regex to check if it is exactly one single word

Tags: python, regex

I am basically trying to match string pattern(wildcard match)
Please carefully look at this -

*(star) - means exactly one word .

This is not a regex pattern...it is a convention.

So,if there patterns like -

```
*.key - '.key.' is preceded by exactly one word(word containing no dots)
*.key.* - '.key.' is preceded and succeeded by exactly one word having no dots
key.* - '.key' preceeds exactly one word .
```

So,

```
"door.key" matches "*.key"
"brown.door.key" doesn't match "*.key".
"brown.key.door" matches "*.key.*"
 but "brown.iron.key.door" doesn't match "*.key.*"
```

So, when I encounter a '*' in pattern, I have replace it with a regex so that it means it is exactly one word.(a-zA-z0-9_).Can anyone please help me do this in python?

Comment: (([A-Za-z0-9_])+\.)?key(\.([A-Za-z0-9_])+)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert your pattern to a regexp, you first need to make sure each character is interpreted literally and not as a special character. We can do that by inserting a `\` in front of any `re` special character. Those characters can be obtained through `sre_parse.SPECIAL_CHARS`.

Since you have a special meaning for `*`, we do not want to escape that one but instead replace it by `\w+`.

### Code

```
import sre_parse

def convert_to_regexp(pattern):
    special_characters = set(sre_parse.SPECIAL_CHARS)
    special_characters.remove('*')

    safe_pattern = ''.join(['\\' + c if c in special_characters else c for c in pattern ])

    return safe_pattern.replace('*', '\\w+')
```

### Example

```
import re

pattern = '*.key'
r_pattern = convert_to_regexp(pattern) # '\\w+\\.key'

re.match(r_pattern, 'door.key') # Match
re.match(r_pattern, 'brown.door.key') # None
```

And here is an example with escaped special characters

```
pattern = '*.(key)'
r_pattern = convert_to_regexp(pattern) # '\\w+\\.\\(key\\)'

re.match(r_pattern, 'door.(key)') # Match
re.match(r_pattern, 'brown.door.(key)') # None
```

### Sidenote

If you intend looking for the output pattern with `re.search` or `re.findall`, you might want to wrap the `re` pattern between `\b` boundary characters.

Answer (score 2):

The conversion rules you are looking for go like this:

- `*` is a word, thus: `\w+`
- `.` is a literal dot: `\.`
- `key` is and stays a literal string
- plus, your samples indicate you are going to match whole strings, which in turn means your pattern should match from the `^` beginning to the `$` end of the string.

Therefore, `*.key` becomes `^\w+\.key$`, `*.key.*` becomes `^\w+\.key\.\w+$`, and so forth..

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EAqora/1/): play with it!

Answer (score 1):

`^` means a string that **starts** with the given set of characters in a regular expression.

`$` means a string that **ends** with the given set of characters in a regular expression.

`\s` means a whitespace character.

`\S` means a non-whitespace character.

`+` means 1 or more characters matching given condition.

Now, you want to match just a single word meaning a string of characters that start and end with non-spaced string. So, the required regular expression is:
`^\S+$`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a combination of "any characters that aren't period" and the start/end anchors.

`*.key` would be `^[^.]*\.key`, and `*.key.*` would be `^[^.]*\.key\.[^.]*$`

EDIT: As tripleee said, `[^.]*`, which matches "any number of characters that aren't periods," would allow whitespace characters (which of course aren't periods), so using `\w+`, "any number of 'word characters'" like the other answers is better.

Comment: Notice that `[^.]` matches whitespace. You might want to replace it with something like `\w` which matches only "word" characters (it is basically a shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`).

Comment: @tripleee, didn't think about that, thanks for mentioning it. Edited it.@shweta, hope it works out.